# UILabel breaks early inside UIStackView

Tags: ios, autolayout, uilabel, uistackview

Given the view hierarchy:

```
UIStackView
--UILabel
--UISwitch
```

The label breaks too early, even if it can be fit to a single line.

Setting `numberOfLines = 1` forces the label to be laid out correctly.

**How to make UILabel perform line break only when needed?**

Code:

```
  private lazy var title: UILabel = {
    let v = UILabel()
    v.numberOfLines = 0
    return v
  }()

  private lazy var toggle = UISwitch()
  private lazy var stack = UIStackView(axis: .horizontal,
                                       distribution: .equalSpacing,
                                       alignment: .center,
                                       views: [title,
                                               toggle])
  func setupConstraints() {
    stack.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
      make.edges.equalTo(contentView.layoutMarginsGuide)
    }
  }
```

**Result:**
[image: Bug]

Setting `numberOfLines = 1` gets me what I'd like to achieve, but the label looses its multi-line functionality:

[image: Desired behavior]

How to force the **desired behavior** without losing support for **multi-line** labels?

When there is a lot of horizontal space, the label gets laid out correctly no matter of the `numberOfLines` property:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set your `UISwitch`'s content hugging and resistance priority to 1000.

And stack view distribution and alignment to `fill`.

Extra Note - If you want label and switch to be top aligned, then set alignment to `top`.

Comment: Hugging/compression resistance did the job.
I went with `fill` for `distribution` and `center` for the `alignment`, the multi-line label work fine.
Exactly, what I wanted, thanks.

Comment: Yes, hugging and compression resistance  with stack views work like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

In your stack view you can give a constraint to your label and switch...

1) give your label leading, top , trailing and bottom constraint. Don't give Width constraint. In trailing constraint take second item Switch.

2) give your switch trailing, top, bottom and Fix width.

Hope it Will work.

Comment: What's the point of the StackView then? In't it the behavior the StackView should provide?

Comment: Stackview devide your view in similar width if you don't give an autolayout.

Comment: That's not true, as I'm using `equalSpacing` distribution.

Comment: I think your approach is wrong..You should learn more about stackview. Bcz stackview spacing equal for two subviews then your label's width will be half of stackview.

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaken. After playing a bit with `.equalSpacing`, I found out, it behaves exactly as you've described.

Answer (score 1):

Add label inside another stack view.

```
UIStackView
--UIStackView
  --UILabel
--UISwitch
```